# In Service Oriented Architecture (SOA), should each service own its own data?

Tags: c#, java, c++, architecture, soa

Under Service Oriented Architecture (SOA), I am interested in the question of whether a service should own its own data or not.

One of the constraints is that if anything fails at any point, we need to be able to roll the state of the entire system back to a prior state so we can retry or resume an operation.

If each service owns its own data, then does this imply that the system deals with change better from the programmers point of view?

However, if each service owns its own data, are there any mechanisms to roll the entire system back to a prior state so a failed operation can be resumed or retried?

Comment: I would have a deterministic system.  In this case, it doesn't make sense to try it again.  Instead of rolling back, I would have to system compensate and continue.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey. Good point. Unfortunately, if something fails, it may require human intervention to fix something else, so the entire process can be resumed or retried.

Comment: Or you could start a new task after manual intervention.  You wouldn't want to stop everything just because one task requires intervention.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey. Yes, I agree. Each task is independent of the others, so if one fails it won't hold up anything else. However, as one of the tasks might have altered something else in the real world before it failed half way through and required human intervention to fix it, if the task is resumed it must be aware of what's being done already (i.e. its prior state must be restored so its aware of the world).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the granularity of what you call services might be wrong. A single service can have multiple endpoints (using same or different protocols) and if a message received on one endpoint requires rolling back state that was received on another it is still an internal transaction within the boundary of the service.

If we consider the simplistic example of order and customer services. The order services may have contracts with messages relating to the whole order or to an order line and cancelling the order will undo state that was affected by both. Usually the address change in the customer service would not be rolled back with that.

Sometimes service actions are tied together in a longer business process, to continue on the example above let's also add an invoicing service. so when we cancel an order we also want to cancel the invoice. However it is important to note that business rules within the realm of the invoicing service can behave differently, for instance and not "roll back" e.g. canceling an order late may require cancelation fees. This sort of long running interaction is what I call a [saga](http://arnon.me/soa-patterns/saga/) (you can see a draft of that pattern [here](http://rgoarchitects.bit.ly/4xNwpp))

Also note that distributed transactions between services is usually not a good idea for several reasons (like holding locks for an external party you don't necessarily trust) you can read more about that [here](http://arnon.me/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/TransactionalIntegration.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you raised here is (partially) solved by the two-phase commit protocol (see [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol))

To avoid implementing this complex algorithm, you can dedicate one of the service of the architecture to data management. If you need data synchronization between different databases, try to do it on the lowest layer (ie system or DBMS).

Comment: Really like your answer, I'll look into that now. And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

SOA system defines more services within one system. This can provide more autonomous services in order to every service can be hosted on different machine.

But it does not mean that you can not provide unified persistent layer for all (domain) models which can point into one storage => simple business transaction when the whole system is spread into more computers or transaction for one system.

Autonomous domain model is useful besides other things during refactoring to avoid situation where a change in one model causes a change in another service => global changes in the whole application.

Answer (score 1):

In short: No.  Services don't "own" data.

Data are truths about the world, and implicitly durable and shared.  Logical services (API) don't always map to real-world data in a 1-1 way.  Physical services (code) are implementations that are very refactorable, which opposes the durable nature of data.

When you partition the data, you lose descriptive power and analytic insight.  But where it really kills you is integrity.  Data cannot be kept coherent across silos as you scale.  For complex data, you need those foreign keys.

Put another way: a platform only has one "logical" DB (per environment), because there is only one universe.  There are many valid reasons to break up a DB, such as HW limits, performance, coordination, replication, and compliance.  But treat them as needed evils, used only when needed.

But I think you may be asking a different question: "should a long-running, data-based transaction be managed by a single authoritative service?"  And typically, that answer is: Yes.  That transaction service can implement the multiple steps to sequence the flow as it sees fit, such as 2-phase commit.  All your other services should use that transaction service to execute the transaction.

BUT!  That transaction service must interact with the DB as a shared resource using only atomic semantics.  That includes all the transaction states (intent, then action, then result) so that recovery and rollbacks are possible.  The database must be empowered to maintain integrity in the event of faults.  I cannot stress this enough: everything, always must decompose into atomic DB operations if you want fault tolerance.

Comment: Really interesting points. Welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for posting this!